# RecyclerView with DiffUtil (ListAdapter) blocks UI thread

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-diffutils, android-listadapter

I am using a `RecyclerView` with [ListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/ListAdapter.html) (which uses [AsyncListDiffer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/AsyncListDiffer) to calculate and animate changes when list is replaced).

The problem is that sometimes when I call `submit()` to update the RecyclerView with new data, it blocks the whole UI thread for 5-10s. This happens after I resume the activity (coming back from home screen), but I am not sure if this is the cause.

I made sure that

- the submitted list has good, expected data
- used `recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);` since it takes up all screen space

This is thread dump while the device is in this non-responding state ([see raw](https://pastebin.com/raw/8feX6gsx)):

```
"main@10549" prio=5 runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:315)
      at android.support.v7.widget.OpReorderer.getLastMoveOutOfOrder(OpReorderer.java:215)
      at android.support.v7.widget.OpReorderer.reorderOps(OpReorderer.java:33)
      at android.support.v7.widget.AdapterHelper.preProcess(AdapterHelper.java:93)
      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.processAdapterUpdatesAndSetAnimationFlags(RecyclerView.java:3583)
      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:3829)
      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3639)
      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4194)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16967)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5584)
      at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:625)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16967)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5584)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:2001)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1844)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1753)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16967)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5584)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:396)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16967)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5584)
      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1189)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16967)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5584)
      at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:142)
      at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:41)
      at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1556)
      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:888)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16967)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5584)
      at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1231)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16967)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5584)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:396)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16967)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5584)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:396)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16967)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5584)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:396)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16967)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5584)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:2001)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1844)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1753)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16967)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5584)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:396)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2769)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16967)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5584)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2547)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2250)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1321)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6732)
      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:894)
      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:696)
      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:631)
      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:880)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5740)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:-1)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:766)
```

Here is my DiffUtil callback:

```
    private static final DiffUtil.ItemCallback<CoinTicker> DIFF_CALLBACK = new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<CoinTicker>() {
        @Override
        public boolean areItemsTheSame(
                @NonNull CoinTicker oldTicker, @NonNull CoinTicker newTicker) {
            // User properties may have changed if reloaded from the DB, but ID is fixed
            return oldTicker.getSlug().equals(newTicker.getSlug()); // String
        }
        @Override
        public boolean areContentsTheSame(
                @NonNull CoinTicker oldTicker, @NonNull CoinTicker newTicker) {
            // NOTE: if you use equals, your object must properly override Object#equals()
            // Incorrectly returning false here will result in too many animations.
            return oldTicker.equals(newTicker); // see below
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChangePayload(@NonNull CoinTicker oldTicker, @NonNull CoinTicker newTicker) {
            return newTicker.getComparisonPrice() - oldTicker.getComparisonPrice();
        }
    };


    // equals for CoinTicker:
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        CoinTicker that = (CoinTicker) o;
        return Double.compare(that.price, price) == 0 && slug.equals(that.slug);
    }
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: You came again LOL !

Comment: Yes, this is a separate and last issue I am having :) Fighting it for one day now :(

Comment: I don't see any problem with above code, can you provide snap-shots from your cycle?

Comment: Are you calling the API again, or it's a huge list with many operations to do before setting to adapter.

Comment: @IbrahimAli you mean [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/8feX6gsx)?

Comment: @ManojPerumarath I am calling the submit() again with new list with updated entries (every 20sec or when user re-enters the activity). This list contains ~2000 objects, each having about 10 primitive values.

Comment: I mean, the problem not here, the problem is somewhere else, maybe in adapter or in the view it self!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Happy to say the "fix" is very easy:

```
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);
```

I don't care about animations. I just wanted a color flash animation on items that are shown on screen, which I do in onBindViewHolder() and it works very fast without any lag!

Answer (score 0):

Comparing two lists is expensive operation. If you're dealing with huge amounts of data it can use a lot of resources. So run your DiffUtils operations in background thread or use [AsyncListDiffer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/AsyncListDiffer.html) which runs on background thread by itself.

Comment: I am using `ListAdapter` which uses `AsyncListDiffer`.

Comment: @Bolling No It's not background if you use it by yourself